# How to get specific month end in VB.NET and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table in a db in SQL Server. Example of the data

```
ID       StartDate                EndDate               Notes
0        2016-01-24 02:50:23      2016-01-25 08:00:05   somethingoranother     
2        2016-01-30 22:00:00      2016-02-05 08:00:05   somethingoranother
```

On the front end (vb code) I am taking each row of the table and counting the time in hours, minutes and seconds. Example:

```
something = something + table.Row(i)("Enddate") - table.Row(i)("startdate")
```

However, when I pull the report for the date, `01/01/2016` to `31/01/2016`, it is including the whole time of row ID 2, up until `5/02/2016`.

How can I get only that time of `30/01/2016` to `31/01/2016 23:59:59` for the month of January?

Comment: When you pull the report for the date 01/01/2016 to 31/01/2016 which rows do you expect to select and why?

Comment: It would help if you could explain your *inputs* to this task and what your *expected* output is. Also, why do you want to exclude anything that happens *during* the last second before midnight? Usually, for continuous data (like datetime), it's better to work with an *exclusive* endpoint (I.e. instead of `<= 31/01/2016 23:59:59` you'd use `< 01/02/2016` - which is generally easier to compute and you don't have to worry about whether you've got the precision of your datetime data type correct)

Comment: What I'm doing is calculating production times. Times and dates have to be very specific. my task is to get the total production times, which I get, except for the part when something is running over into another month. Therefore I would like to calculate only up, until the end of the month.

Comment: I guess some of the confusion is why you're focussing on row ID 2 in your question - doesn't row ID 0 have exactly the same issue, given that they both have the same `EndDate`? Or if the two rows should be treated differently, it's unclear (to me) what the distinguishing factor(s) may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, you only want the records from a specific date untill a given date. The part of code that does the addition in your frontend would have to check if the row should be counted in your sum:

```
Dim fromthis As Date = #01/01/2016#
Dim tothis AS Date = #01/02/2016#

For i As Integer = 1 To XXX
    If(table.Row(i)("startdate") >= fromthis and tothis > table.Row(i)("Enddate"))
        something = something + table.Row(i)("Enddate") - table.Row(i)("startdate")

    If(table.Row(i)("startdate") < fromthis and table.Row(i)("Enddate") > fromthis)
        something = something + table.Row(i)("Enddate") - fromthis

    If(table.Row(i)("startdate") < tothis and table.Row(i)("Enddate") > tothis)
        something = something + tothis - table.Row(i)("startdate")

    End If
Next
```

Or your query that returns the rows for your table could restrict the results for the given margins. This approach is cleaner, as you don't load unwanted data. Something like:

```
SELECT ID
, CASE WHEN StartDate < @fromDate THEN @fromDate ELSE StartDate END as StartDate
, CASE WHEN EndDate > @toDate THEN @toDate ELSE EndDate END as EndDate
, Notes
FROM yourtable
WHERE (StartDate >= @fromDate)
OR EndDate <= @toDate
OR (StartDate < @fromDate AND EndDate > @toDate)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution. But for your code I think `toThis` should be `#01/02/2016#` and `tothis <= table.Row(i)("Enddate"))` should be `tothis > table.Row(i)("Enddate"))`.

Comment: @RaulSebastian thanks for your answer. i was thinking along these lines, the problem is that you cannot hard code the dates. this is one of the issues I'm faced with. And we cannot ignore the last row (Row ID 2) still need that one day aswell.

Comment: your parameters are ofcourse variable and not hardcoded, I have just given an example as your question doesn't give an insight how you pass the values for duration to the code. Also read the code again, RowID 2 is not ignored, only the enddate is replaced by your upper boundry. This would ofcourse only work for a specific timespan with a from and to duration, as I thought that is what you need. In case you want to group duration sums by month, I could add an sql for that.

Comment: Thanks @RaulSebastian, I did try something very similar to your code. Eventually got it working. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe this is what you meant:

```
create table #test(
    Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    StartDate datetime not null,
    EndDate datetime not null
)

insert into #test values ('2016-01-24 02:50:23', '2016-02-05 08:00:05')
insert into #test values ('2016-01-30 22:00:00', '2016-02-05 08:00:05')
insert into #test values ('2016-01-01 22:00:00', '2016-01-01 23:00:00')


select * from #test


declare @startCheck datetime 
declare @endCheck datetime 

set @startCheck = '2016-01-01'
set @endCheck = '2016-02-01'


select
    id,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    [Hours in January] = 
        case
            when endDate >= @endCheck then datediff( hour, startDate, @endCheck )
            when endDate < @endCheck then datediff( hour, startDate, endDate )
        end
from
    #test
where
    (1=1)
    and ( startDate >= @startCheck )

drop table #test
```

result

```
Id  StartDate               EndDate                 Hours in January  
1   2016-01-24 02:50:23.000 2016-02-05 08:00:05.000 190  
2   2016-01-30 22:00:00.000 2016-02-05 08:00:05.000 26  
3   2016-01-01 22:00:00.000 2016-01-01 23:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: Hi @shadow, I'm not trying to complicate things in sql. I'm trying to keep the query as simple as possible. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming row 0 should be treated similarly to row 2, I think this does what you want:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,StartDate datetime not null,EndDate datetime not null,
                  Notes varchar(217) not null)
insert into @t(ID,StartDate,EndDate,Notes) values
(0,'2016-01-24T02:50:23','2016-02-05T08:00:05','somethingoranother'),
(2,'2016-01-30T22:00:00','2016-02-05T08:00:05','somethingoranother')

declare @Start datetime
declare @End datetime

select @Start = '20160101',@End='20160201'

;With Clamped as (
    select
        ID,
        CASE WHEN StartDate > @Start THEN StartDate ELSE @Start END as StartDate,
        CASE WHEN EndDate < @End THEN EndDate ELSE @End END as EndDate,
        Notes
    from
        @t
    where
        StartDate < @End and
        @Start < EndDate
)
select
    *,
    DATEDIFF(second,StartDate,EndDate) as ElapsedTime
from
    Clamped
```

(`@Start` and `@End` could, of course, be parameters - this is just for the sample code).

The result is:

```
ID          StartDate               EndDate                 Notes               ElapsedTime
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------------- -----------
0           2016-01-24 02:50:23.000 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 somethingoranother  680977
2           2016-01-30 22:00:00.000 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 somethingoranother  93600
```

So, row 0 is contributing 189 hours, 9 minutes and 37 minutes and row 2 is contributing 26 hours. Those values seem to be correct, if I've understood your problem.

It's up to you whether you wish to aggregate this data here within the final query or to do that within your VB. I leave the translation of the times in seconds into units of hours, minutes and seconds as something trivially done in VB also, using the `TimeSpan` class. (It's not as easily done within SQL Server, since it doesn't have a corresponding data type that represents time spans rather than times of day)